# How to dynamically replace part of a class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic class that starts with `z-`. How can I dynamically change `z-` into `fa-` onload?

```
From <a href="#" class="z-dynamic">Link</a>

to <a href="#" class="fa-dynamic">Link</a>
```

I only want to replace a part of the class, not the whole class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and call [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) with a callback function to modify the attribute for each element. In my example, I use a the string [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to ensure that all classes in the list that start with `z-` are replaced, and only those instances of that string. Then just wrap it in the [jQuery document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) wrapper, and you are ready to go.

```
$(function(){
    //Select only the a tags with "z-" in the "class" attribute, and modify the attribute using a callback function.
    $('a[class*="z-"]').attr('class', function(index, attr) {
        //Return the updated string, being sure to only replace z- at the start of a class name.
        return attr.replace(/(^|\s)z-/g, 'fa-');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var self = $("a.z-dynamic");
    self.attr("class", self.attr("class").replace("z-", "fa-"));
});
```

This will change

```
From <a href="#" class="z-dynamic">Link</a>

to <a href="#" class="fa-dynamic">Link</a>
```

Comment: I think the `dynamic` part is unknown.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You means you think it is coming from a variable?

Comment: void, "dynamic" part keeps on changing so I only need the "z-" part. thanks

Comment: I'm new here so I need more "reputations" to upvote. Pls upvote my question instead for me to get more reputations :) thanks

Comment: You mark it as the correct answer please so as to not create trouble to other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to that node already, you could easily apply a little regex alongside `.replace()` to the className.

```
anchor.className = anchor.className.replace(/z-/, 'fa-');
```